# How to plot $(x,y)$ phase diagram?

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot the $(x,y)$ phase diagram under this constraint: 
$$-\frac{x}{3} - \sqrt{\left( \frac{x}{3} \right)^2 - \frac{y}{6}} = 0$$

I tried to use [ContourPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html)

```
ContourPlot[-x/3 - Sqrt[(x/3)^2 - y/6], 
       {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

1. The problem that I am not sure how to interpret the plot.
2. Why don't I get only one counter?

[image]

Comment: `ContourPlot[-x/(3) - Sqrt[(x/(3))^2 - y/(6)] == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]` would just give you only one contour.

Comment: Solution of this equation is `y=0` at `x<=0`. Are you sure that this describes a phase diagram?

Comment: What does this have to do with phase or phase diagrams?